# javafx Shape3D with border

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-3d

I'm making application with huge mass of 3D shapes and I need them fully transparent and with border. I tried find any way to apply border to Shape3D, specifically to Box and Sphere but I can't find anything. So my questions are:

- Is there any way how to add border to Shape3D?
- If yes, how to do it?

Comment: I guess you're not talking about drawing wireframes using `drawMode` `DrawMode.LINE`???

Comment: You can't really add a border to an arbitrary Shape3D in JavaFX via the API.

Comment: You could create a second mesh which essentially traces the vertices of the first mesh using an algorithm like the FXyz3d.org PolyLine3D algorithm.  This would essentially create a skeleton structure as a single mesh.  Whatever algorithm you implemented would have to mimic the winding pattern of the original mesh to an extent. This would probably have to be custom for any particular mesh. I'm not sure it would be possible to have a generic tracing algorithm like that.  (at least in JavaFX 3D)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no option to add borders to 3d shapes, but you can use very thin cyllinders instead (only works for boxes though):

```
    public void createBoxLines(double contW, double contH, double contD, double x, double y, double z) {
       //You call this method to create a box with a size and location you put in
        //This method calls the createLine method for all the sides of your rectangle
        Point3D p1 = new Point3D(x, y, z);
        Point3D p2 = new Point3D(contW + x, y, z);
        Point3D p3 = new Point3D(x, contH + y, z);
        Point3D p4 = new Point3D(contW + x, contH + y, z);
        createLine(p1, p2);
        createLine(p1, p3);
        createLine(p3, p4);
        createLine(p2, p4);

        Point3D p5 = new Point3D(x, y, contD + z);
        Point3D p6 = new Point3D(contW + x, y, contD + z);
        Point3D p7 = new Point3D(x, contH + y, contD + z);
        Point3D p8 = new Point3D(contW + x, contH + y, contD + z);
        createLine(p5, p6);
        createLine(p5, p7);
        createLine(p7, p8);
        createLine(p6, p8);

        createLine(p1, p5);
        createLine(p2, p6);
        createLine(p3, p7);
        createLine(p4, p8);
    }

    double strokewidth = 1;
    public void createLine(Point3D origin, Point3D target) {        
        //creates a line from one point3d to another

        Point3D yAxis = new Point3D(0, 1, 0);
        Point3D diff = target.subtract(origin);
        double height = diff.magnitude();

        Point3D mid = target.midpoint(origin);
        Translate moveToMidpoint = new Translate(mid.getX(), mid.getY(), mid.getZ());

        Point3D axisOfRotation = diff.crossProduct(yAxis);
        double angle = Math.acos(diff.normalize().dotProduct(yAxis));
        Rotate rotateAroundCenter = new Rotate(-Math.toDegrees(angle), axisOfRotation);

        Cylinder line = new Cylinder(strokewidth, height);

        line.getTransforms().addAll(moveToMidpoint, rotateAroundCenter);

        myGroup.getChildren().add(line);
    }
```

The createLine method can be used seperately to make lines between different points.
I cant provide many comments for that method, because I basically copied it from some blog. Although I'm having a hard time finding that blog again.

Comment: Consider adding some comments in your code to clarify what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Alex Quilliam thanks for the code i was able to improve my program.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/79ojm.png

```
Cylinder line = new Cylinder(strokewidth, height);
```

↓

```
Box line = new Box(strokewidth, height, strokewidth);
```

[JavaFX_3D_Cube_Outline_Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2biip.png)